# Why can Facebook Conversion API, instead of Pixel, overcome iOS 14 privacy policies?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, adblock, facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

They claimed that the Facebook Conversion API is the solution to overcoming iOS 14's privacy policies, however I still have two questions:

1. I understand that the Conversion API is sent from the server to Facebook, but the event must still be triggered from the client side, correct? So, if adblock can block all existing tracking domains, would the conversion API, like pixel, become obsolete?
2. If the event is sent from the server to Facebook, there is no way for the event to know the client's device information or anything else, so this information must be coming from the client, but iOS 14 has blocked those information access authority if the user selects "Not Allowed," so the conversion API should still be useless compared to pixel, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events are sent from the client to a conversions api service on the client domain, so they’re not blocked by cross-domain privacy restrictions.

The service can then relay those events over to facebook, server to server.

```
client => fb.mydomain.com => facebook.com
```

Comment: That's where I'm confused right now: if the client's adblock chooses to block `fb.mydomain.com`, it will also be unable to track, correct?

Comment: Anyway, I believe the site 'fb.mydomain.com' is less likely to be blocked by adblock because it is a corporate subdomain, but my second question is, if the user clicks "Not Allowed" in the iOS 14 tracking box, it will have less information to monitor, correct? So it has the same power as a pixel, right? Because the quantity of data that can be tracked is restricted.

Comment: If your site is on `mydomain.com` iOS isn’t going to block requests to a subdomain. With iOS tracking off you may not get the user’s “advertiser id” and such, but you’ll still get event information that would otherwise be blocked. Disclosure: This is not my area of expertise.